# displaying output of Renci.ssh.net cmd on Vb.net listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am developing a program in vb.net using Visual studio 2015 community edition. I am trying to list files of a remote directory on Linux server.

I have used Renci.Sshnet.cmd to execute the (ls -l function) on the remote server after connecting to it .  The output I want to put in the list box but it gives all output as a single line and not in sequential order.

```
Imports Renci.SshNet

Dim connInfo As New Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo(hostname, username, password)
Dim sshClient As New Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo)

'Need to hold the command'
Dim cmdnumber As Renci.SshNet.SshCommand

Using sshClient
    'connect to the server'
    sshClient.Connect()

    'Run the command and put the results into the cmd object. In this case'
    'I am just running a directory list'
    cmdnumber = sshClient.RunCommand("ls -1")
    Listbox1.Items.Add(cmdnumber.Result)
```

Instead of having multiple lines of output, the output is given as single line .

Comment: Are there non-printable chars in the string returned?

Answer (score 0):

The `Result` string most likely contains Linux-style newlines that need to be converted to Windows-style, that is, `vbLf` to `vbNewline`.

```
cmdnumber.Result.Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbLf, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbNewline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(cmdnumber.Result)
```

With

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(cmdnumber.Result.Split(vbLf))
```

As someone told, odds are the lines are separated by a linux linefeed (vbLf) you can just toggle a breakpoint and a variable watch to be sure.